# How can you save the function calculation, so that you can see the previous total amount calculated?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the function of saving the previous calculated total amount (total amount comes from my function), and display it, so that the user can the "history" of the previous calculated items. I am new to HTML and Javascript, and have tried all other materials, but i cant seem to get it right. Now i have deleted previous steps and is left with the form and the function, and desperately hope one of you guys can help me out!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("test").reset();
    
} 
  function priceCalculation(xform) {
        price = 318
        var quantity = xform.text1.value * 1;
        var orderDate = new Date(xform.text2.value);
        var deliveryDate = new Date(xform.text3.value);
        // calculating quantity discount
        if (quantity => 10)
            {
                quantityDiscount = (quantity-10)*price*0.075; 
            }
        else
            quantityDiscount = 0;
        // calculating delivery discount
        if (1 <= orderDate.getDay() && orderDate.getDay() <= 3)
            {
                //alert("delivery1");
                if ((deliveryDate - orderDate)/86400000 > 2)
                    {
                        //alert("delivery2");
                        deliveryDiscount = quantity*0.055*price;
                    }
                else
                    deliveryDiscount = 0;
            }
        else
            deliveryDiscount = 0;
        var amount = price*quantity - quantityDiscount - deliveryDiscount;
    {
                document.TESTING.OUTPUT1.value = amount
    }
        return;
    }
   
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
        #button{padding-left: 35px;}
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>ICT-Applied</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="TESTING" id="test">
        <table border="1" width="1000" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6"> 
                    <h1>Assignment III-B Group 10</h1></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h3>Number of packages</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Order date</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Delivery date</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Click to calcute your price</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>Total Amount</h3></th>
                <th>
                    <h3>New calculation</h3></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
<td>
    <input id=text1 name=text1></td>
<td>
    <input type=date id=text2 name=text2></td>
<td>
    <input type=date id = text3 name text3></td>
<td id="button">
    <input id=submit1 type=submit value='Calculate!' name=submit1 onclick="return priceCalculation(this.form)"></td>
                
<td><input type="number" name="OUTPUT1" id="output"></td>

<td><input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form"></td>
                
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are doing. You select `number of packages` then click `calculate` and then what (event this step fails)? Do you want to send the contents of that form to the server? Or you want to just accumulate price over many clicks without sending it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the total amount, save it in the browser's local storage and use it next time to get that amount back. You can do so by this:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
  localStorage.setItem("yourkey", "value corresponding to key");
  //eg: localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Then you can retrieve this value whenever you want using:

```
localStorage.getItem("your key");
```

Note: this will only work until the browser cache is not cleared by the user. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to point out in my case, what the "yourkey", and "Value corresponding to key" is, since its the calculated amount i want to store. (Sorry for the questions, i started recently learning this).

Comment: in your case the keys can be like 'previousAmount1' , 'previousAmount2' , etc and the values will be the amount that you want to save as history.